# How to click on td element using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I'm Fairley new to selenium and I'm attempting click on a table but I can't seem to find it.
Below I have posted my code along with a screen shot of what I'm trying to click on.

Here is my code:

```
competitorPrices = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Competitor Prices"))).click()
```

HTML snapshot:

[image: Html Code]

Error:

[image: This is the error I'm presented with]

Element snapshot:

[image: Here's what I would like to click on]

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
...
import time
time.sleep(5)
xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Competitor Prices')]"
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
competitorPrices = driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)
```

Sometimes the method element_to_be_clickable doesn't work out of the box. In this cases to debug I use time.sleep so I can understand better the problem

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a `<td>` not an `<a>` tag. Hence *`LINK_TEXT`* won't work.

[image: table_td]

Moreover `click()` doesn't returns anything, so `competitorPrices` will be always *`None`* which you may remove.

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#tblTabStrip td[ch^='CompetitorPrices']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tblTabStrip']//td[text()='Competitor Prices']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```